# Gem Rails Admin Views

Tags: rubygems, configure, rails-admin

I am using the sferik/railsadmin gem in my rails application. Is it possible to configure its views? If yes , how to generate its views and configure them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override a view by creating your own at the same path. There is also a rake task to help you - `rake rails_admin:copy_views`

Think carefully though, you would have to update your modified views everytime rails_admin changed it's internals about a lot.

Comment: Seems it was deprecated, any other way to generate views?

Comment: this has been deprecated and no longer works.  based on the documentation, it seems like they are more strongly encouraging making edits via the DSL, however documentation is somewhat lacking.  an example of list view table styling is here however:  https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List-view-table-styling

Comment: it appears that the functionality was removed from the repo at some point.  you could however fork the project and merge this particular commit to get what you want if you absolutely need to do this (this isn't ideal long-term however).. https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/commit/db768becbfdf423f660bae06adc21082a692f582

Comment: unable to generate views by using this command "rake rails_admin:copy_views"  please help me to genarate view of rails admin

Answer (score 1):

RailsAdmin also allows you to configure the views and navigation without actually copying over all the views. This way is nice since it still allows all the dynamic magic to happen while providing some control over what models are shown, fields are shown, order of fields, navigation, etc. [The wiki explains how to configure in detail.](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL) and [here for navigation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation)